# count data from multiple year and group by location

Tags: mysql

I want to make a chart about population in some area, 
here's an example of my table;

```
mmr                              mmrp
+-------+--------+--------+     +-------+------------+
| rm    |city    |region  |     | rm    | date       |
+-------+--------+--------+     +-------+------------+
| 123   |city_a  |region1 |     | 123   | 2012-xx-xx |
| 124   |city_a  |region1 |     | 124   | 2013-xx-xx |
| 210   |city_b  |region1 |     | 210   | 2012-xx-xx |
| 211   |city_c  |region2 |     | 211   | 2011-xx-xx |
| 212   |city_d  |region3 |     | 212   | 2011-xx-xx |
| 213   |city_e  |region3 |     | 213   | 2013-xx-xx |
+-------+--------+--------+     +-------+------------+
```

I want to count the amount of people **in the region1 grouped by city**, and people **outside region1 group by region**, and ***within 3 years***, here's what I'm trying to achieve;

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| area  | 2011   | 2012   | 2013   |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|city_a | 0      | 1      | 1      |
|city_b | 0      | 1      | 0      |
|region2| 1      | 0      | 0      |
|region3| 1      | 0      | 1      |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

so far I only know how to count in spesific **region** and ***year***, this is what I've done;

```
SELECT a.city, count(b.rm) as 2013
FROM mmr a join mrpp b on (a.rm=b.rm)
where year(b.date) = 2013 and a.region like 'region1' GROUP BY city
```

but it only show count from region1 in 2013, is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(a.region = 'region1', city, region) AS area,
       SUM(year(b.date) = 2011) AS `2011`,
       SUM(year(b.date) = 2012) AS `2012`,
       SUM(year(b.date) = 2013) AS `2013`
FROM mmr a JOIN mrpp b ON a.rm = b.rm
WHERE b.date >= `2011-01-01`
GROUP BY area
```

Comment: I've tried your query, but the result is more than 100 records, I tried to make it simple by get a top 10 in recent year by adding this query `order by '2013' DESC limit 10` but it did not work, the order is wrong, what should I do?

Comment: It should be `ORDER BY \`2013\`` -- backticks, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.city area, sum(if(year(b.date)=2011,1,0) as 2011,
 sum(if(year(b.date)=2012,1,0) as 2012,
 sum(if(year(b.date)=2013,1,0) as 2013
FROM mmr a join mrpp b on (a.rm=b.rm)
where year(b.date) between 2011 and 2013
and a.region = 'region1' 
GROUP BY city

union

SELECT a.region area, sum(if(year(b.date)=2011,1,0) as 2011,
 sum(if(year(b.date)=2012,1,0) as 2012,
 sum(if(year(b.date)=2013,1,0) as 2013
FROM mmr a join mrpp b on (a.rm=b.rm)
where year(b.date) between 2011 and 2013
and a.region <> 'region1'
GROUP BY a.region
```